# How to get last record?

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table with following schema
TableReassignment

```
Id
StepId
FromUserId
ToUserId
```

Sample Data For TableReassignment: There may or may not be any record for particular step

```
1 , Step1 , UserA, UserB 
2 , Step1 , UserB, UserC 
3 , Step1 , UserC, UserD 
4 , Step1 , UserD, UserE 
5 , Step1 , UserF, UserG 
6 , Step2 , UserB, UserC 
7 , Step2 , UserC, UserD 
8 , Step2 , UserE, Userf
```

Also User Table

```
UserId
UserName
```

Also StepUserDetails

```
StepId,
StepUserId
```

Sample Data For StepUserDetails:

```
Step1, UserA
Step2, UserB
Step3, UserC
Step4, UserD
```

My Requirement is, That I want StepUserDetails with existing StepUsers and if they are reassigned then the last reassigned user.

Expected output should be like

```
Step1, UserG
Step2, UserF
Step3, UserC
Step4, UserD
```

Comment: unless i don't get your question well: `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Table WHERE StepId= 'Step1' Order by Id desc`

Comment: The question asked after the edit is something different from what was asked in the original version. Can you also provide the expected output?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos check updated one

Comment: To be honest I'm now confused as to what your actual requirement is.

Comment: Reassignment table is for reassigning one user to another user, I only want the last user for that step

Comment: I have explained, @GiorgosBetsos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
WITH ReassignmentCTE AS (
   SELECT StepId, ToUserId, 
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY stepId ORDER BY Id DESC) AS rn
   FROM Reassignment
)    
SELECT s.StepId, COALESCE(c.ToUserId, s.StepUserId) AS StepUserId
FROM StepUserDetails AS s
LEFT JOIN ReassignmentCTE AS c ON s.StepId = c.StepId AND c.rn = 1
```

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/WLGN89659)

Comment: Yes, exactly what i mean, i don't quite understand why this one need to be complicated, when just need to sort by id and get First record - like my comment . Unless I don't get what OP mean

Answer (score 1):

You could use a subquery

```
  select ToUserId
  from my_table where Id =(
  select max(Id)
  from my_table 
  where stepId='Step1'
  )
```

or  a join

```
  select ToUserID
  from my_table 
  inner Join (
        select StepId, max(Id) my_id
        from my_table 
        group by StepId
  ) t on t.my_id = my_table.Id  and StepId  ='Step1'
```

and for your updated  question

```
  select a.StepID, a.ToUserID
  from my_table  a
  inner Join (
        select StepId, max(Id) my_id
        from my_table 
        group by StepId
  ) t on t.my_id = a.Id
```

Comment: I have updated my question, the requirement is bit different.